# How to select multiple checkboxes in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular6

I am using a checkbox in angular to select more than one option and I am trying to get the value of the checkbox in one object, not in an array. I have tried the following code:

```html
component.html file

     <form [formGroup]="myForm">
        <div class="form-group">
       
          <div class="input-group">
              <div *ngFor="let data of skillsArray">
                  <p><input type="checkbox" (change)="onChange(data.value, $event.target.checked)"> {{data.skill}}</p>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

```js
component.ts file

formValue(){
        this.myForm = this.fb.group({
            VFields: this.fb.array([])
          });
    }
    // selectedValue:Object;
    onChange(value: any, isChecked: boolean) {
        const skillFormArray = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.VFields;
       
        if (isChecked) {
            skillFormArray.push(new FormControl(value));
        } else {
          let index = skillFormArray.controls.findIndex(x => x.value == value)
          skillFormArray.removeAt(index);
        }
        
      }
```

The output is:

{
  "VFields": [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3"
  ]
}

But I want it to be like this:

{
"VFields":"1,2,3"
}

So how we can do this?

Comment: Done i got a solution .
VFields: sdata.toString(),

Comment: Then, consider answering your own question, so other people can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use toString() method on sdata.
you will get desired result